# Error generating csv file using delayed-job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, delayed-job

I have to generate a csv report and upload it to s3. I am using paperclip to store file as an attachment and store it in s3.

everything work fine but if i try to use delayed_job, for some random reports are generated with nill fields. In my table paperclip fields are empty for those reports.